# Using transfinite induction to compute fundamental groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups, transfinite-induction

I want to compute the fundamental group of a space containing  [comb space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_space) along with boundary of $I \times I$ where I is $[0,1]$. Here is my attempt using transfinite induction and Van Kampen.

Let's call the given space $X$. Consider an open set $U_{1}$ say $(-1, 2/3) \times (-1, 2)$ and  $U_{2}$  $(5/4, 2) \times (-1, 2)$. Then it's easily seen that hypothesis of Van Kampen Theorem is satisfied and $U_{1}$ $\cap$ $U_{2}$ is contractible while $U_{2}$ $\cap$ $X$ is homotopic equivalent to $S^{1}$ and $U_{1}$ $\cap$ $X$ is homotopic equivalent to one less vertical line in $X$. By induction hypothesis we assume that Fundamental group of $U_{1}$ $\cap$ $X$ is countable free product of $\mathbb{Z}$. Hence so is the Fundamental group of $X$.

Comment: Note that $X$ is not homeomorphic to a CW complex as any CW complex is locally contractible and $X$ is not locally connected. Also, the Hawaiian earring is not locally simply connected, so it's not a CW complex either. The fundamental group of the Hawaiian earring is much more complicated, as is mentioned in the article you have linked.

Comment: My bad!! I thought since we have $CW$ structure when vertical lines are finite, so is the case when vertical lines are infinite. However is my calculation for the fundamental group correct ?

Comment: You could use the formulation of van Kampen's theorem in Hatcher's [*Algebraic Topology*](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html), chapter 1, page 43, with $(1,\frac12)$ as the basepoint. That's how I would do it. I don't know if the method you suggest works. How would the induction start?

Comment: Sorry, for my last comment. I just see that there is no suitable cover we could use since some open set would contain almost all vertical lines. So let's just stick to your approach.

Comment: Take the space with just the boundary of $I \times I$ as the base case and induction is on the number of vertical segments.